# Overriding inline style not working in Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

A site I have created is behaving strangely in MS Edge Browser (and IE too): 
http://bristolenergynetwork.org/

On the element header#fancy-header the stylesheet css of background-size: intial !important should be overriding the inline style of background-size: cover. Edge developer tools show the latter as crossed out, suggesting it is being overridden but it is not as the banner should appear below the logo and menu as it does on Chrome. If you uncheck the crossed out style the site looks as it should suggesting that the override is not taking place as developer tools suggests.

[image]

Is this a bug in Edge or is something else causing this behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the property to **inherit**, it works for me.

```
 body.home header#fancy-header {
    background-size: inherit !important;
}
```

You can find the different background size property at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp